# how to get value from JSP to controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

i have view login like this

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href='<c:url value = "/resources/images/favicon.png"/>'/>



<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value = "/resources/js/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>'/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value = "/resources/fonts/font-awesome-4/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>'/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value = "/resources/css/style.css"/>'/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='<c:url value = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,700,800"/>'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='<c:url value = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,200,100"/>'/>
</head>
<body class="texture">

    <div id="cl-wrapper" class="login-container">
        <div class="middle-login">
            <div class="block-flat">
                <div class="header">                            
                    <h3 class="text-center"><img class="logo-img" src="resources/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>Halodoc Coupon</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form:form method="post" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;" class="form-horizontal" action="j_spring_security_check" modelAttribute="users">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4 class="title"><span style="color: red">${message}</span></h4>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                            <input type="email" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Email" required>
                                        </div> <!-- end input-group email-->
                                    </div> <!-- end col-sm-12 email-->
                                </div><!-- end form-group email-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control">
                                        </div> <!-- end input-group password-->
                                    </div> <!-- end col-sm-12 password-->
                                </div><!-- end form-group password-->
                        </div> <!-- end content -->
                        <div class="foot">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Login">Login</button>
                        </div> <!-- end foot -->
                    </form:form>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end block-flat -->
            <div class="text-center out-links"><a href="#">&copy; 2016 Polinasi Iddea Investama</a></div>
        </div> <!-- end middle-login -->

    </div><!-- end login container -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/behaviour/general.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/behaviour/voice-commands.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.labels.js"/>'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then my controller like this

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
LoginDao loginDao;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
public String getUserDefault() {
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView getLoginForm(@ModelAttribute Users users,
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String message = "";
    System.out.println(users.getUsername() + " | "+ users.getPassword() + " | " );
    if (error != null) {
        message = "Incorrect username or password !";
    } else if (logout != null) {
        message = "Logout successful !";
    }
    return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
}

@RequestMapping("/admin**")
public String getAdminProfile() {
    return "admin";
}

@RequestMapping("/user**")
public String getUserProfile() {
    return "user";
}

@RequestMapping("/403")
public ModelAndView getAccessDenied() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    String username = "";
    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        username = userDetail.getUsername();
    }

    return new ModelAndView("403", "username", username);
}

}
```

and my spring security like this

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        default-target-url="/home" username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

i have problem to show value username and password, i tried always null value,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView getLoginForm(@ModelAttribute Users users,
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String message = "";
    System.out.println(users.getUsername() + " | "+ users.getPassword() + " | " );
    if (error != null) {
        message = "Incorrect username or password !";
    } else if (logout != null) {
        message = "Logout successful !";
    }
    return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
}
```

how to get value from my view jsp to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
<input type="email" id="username" name="username" />
```

You should use spring form's input taglib instead. For example:

```
<form:input path="email" id="username" .... />
```

Learn more about [Spring's tablib here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag), or you could read [complete references here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html).

Comment: iam already use that but i got an error HTTP Status 500 - /WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp (line: 40, column: 122) equal symbol expected

Comment: "Equal symbol expected" mostly caused by you forgot to add `=` symbol when adding JSP's directive, declaring, tag libraries, etc. Put your JSP with `<form:input .... />` here, and we could investigate from there.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
@ModelAttribute Users users
```

to

```
@ModelAttribute("users") Users users
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you either never created form with input or you have an input but dont have the form. The problem is here:

If you use **form** tag:

```
<form:form ...
```

your input also need to include **form** input tag:

```
<form:input path="" value="" />
```

And if you doesnt want to use **form** tag,you just declare normal form like this:

```
<form method="post" ...
```

And normal input like this:

```
<input name="" value="" />
```

and dont forget to remove the **modelAttribute** in form attribute also **@ModelAttribute** in @Controller.

In your case right now,you are binding the form with **@ModelAttribute("users")** but the form doesnt find any tag for form input and the form actually send no input at all.